# converting decimal to string and string to decimal using char type

Tags: c++, string

My code is not giving me exact values. Can somebody tell me what's wrong? A few values give me the correct answer, but try `78`, `79`, `80` etc and you will know.

If you could somehow correct it, that would be great.

```
//hi // Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int stringToDecimal(string X)
{
    int digit = 0;
    //I believe there is some fault here.

    for (int i = 0;i < (X.length() -1); i++)
    {
        char c = X[i] + 48;     
        digit = (c + (10 ^ i) )+ digit;
    }
    return digit;
}

int countDigit(int n)
{
    int count = 0;
    while (n != 0) {
        n = n / 10;
        ++count;
    }
    return count;
}

//I believe there is some fault here too
string DecimalToString(int x)
{
    string a= "";
    for (int i =0 ; i < countDigit(x); i++)
    {
        char digit = (x / (10 ^  i)) % 10;
        char c = digit + 48;
        a = a +c;
    }
    cout << endl; 
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "enter an integer" << endl;
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    cout << DecimalToString(a) << endl;
    cout << stringToDecimal(DecimalToString(a));
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Recommendation: Rather than 48, which could mean just about anything, use `'0'` the meaning of which is obvious to just about anyone able to read this question. Assuming that 48 really is intended to be the ASCII code for 48. Also note that `'0'` is pretty much universal and ASCII, while dominant, isn't the only character encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
digit = (c + (10 ^ i) )+ digit;
```

the `^` operator is not the exponentiation operator, it's the bitwise xor operator.

You will need to use `std::pow` for this:

```
digit = (c + std::pow(10, i) )+ digit;
```

You have to do the similar thing in the other function as well.

Instead of the `pow` function, you could also hold on to a variable that you modify in the loop:

```
int prod = 1;
for (...)
{
  // ...
  digit = (c + prod) + digit;
  prod *= 10;
}
```

Comment: Prefer not to use the `pow` function.  The `pow` function is a floating point function, returns floating point.  There may be some conversion issues or propagation of error due to converting from floating point to integer.  There are better methods, such as maintaining the power value in a temporary variable and multiplying this variable by 10 in each iteration.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Fair enough, added that option as well.

Comment: the second function is good. but StringtoDecimal is not working. could you write that correctly?

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, the algorithm is as follows (applies to binary as well):

```
Set value to zero.  
For each digit (left to right):  
    multiply value by base (a.k.a. 10).
    add in digit value
    end-for
```

Given a string as input, the code may look somewhat like this:

```
std::string number_as_text = "85";
int value = 0;
const size_t number_text_length = number_as_text.length();
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < number_text_length; ++i)
{
  value = value * 10; // Shift left by one digit.
  value += number_as_text[i] - '0';
}
```

The algorithm requires no division, which makes the processor very happy.
There are no floating point conversions.